# GWT upload - Uploading single file twice

Tags: gwt, file-upload, gwtupload

I am currently working on a GWT screen which has a requirement of browsing GWT file once but submitting it to server many times.
But in GWT upload after clicking on submit. or even submitting using singleUploader.submit() method. File browsed by FileInputType get cleared.

Can you suggest any method to upload single file many times using gwt-upload?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "submitting it to server many times"? Do you want to upload multiple copies of the same file without the user having to browse for it again? If so, _why_? Or do you mean doing different things with the uploaded file once it's on the servlet (which you should be able to do already)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is possible. I would try to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest
and would create (using native javascript) two instances of XmlHttpRequest and would try to send them both.
The anticipated problem here is that `input` element on the page would receive incoming events as a result of the upload process (loadstart, progress, etc). I am in doubt that it can properly handle two parallel flows of those events successfully.

Another way is to try to send the upload requests consequently, but then you will have to generate second form submit. Which is not trivial, and browsers do not support that on the high level.